# Tabs with viewpager fragments, working in wrong context?

Tags: android, android-fragments, achartengine

**The problem:**

To my understanding I try to update the `chartview` outside the `activity` in a (worker?) `thread`

> (GraphicalView chartView =
>   ChartFactory.getLineChartView(getActivity(), dataSet, mRenderer);)

I use `WeatherLib` as a `library` to receive weather data.
Anyone knows where I go wrong here?

**Code:**

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.survivingwithandroid.weather.lib.WeatherClient;
import com.survivingwithandroid.weather.lib.WeatherConfig;
import com.survivingwithandroid.weather.lib.exception.WeatherLibException;
import com.survivingwithandroid.weather.lib.exception.WeatherProviderInstantiationException;
import com.survivingwithandroid.weather.lib.model.DayForecast;
import com.survivingwithandroid.weather.lib.model.HourForecast;
import com.survivingwithandroid.weather.lib.model.WeatherHourForecast;
import com.survivingwithandroid.weather.lib.provider.IWeatherProvider;
import com.survivingwithandroid.weather.lib.provider.WeatherProviderFactory;
import com.survivingwithandroid.weather.lib.provider.openweathermap.OpenweathermapProviderType;
import com.survivingwithandroid.weather.lib.request.WeatherRequest;

import org.achartengine.ChartFactory;
import org.achartengine.GraphicalView;
import org.achartengine.chart.BarChart;
import org.achartengine.chart.PointStyle;
import org.achartengine.model.RangeCategorySeries;
import org.achartengine.model.XYMultipleSeriesDataset;
import org.achartengine.model.XYSeries;
import org.achartengine.renderer.XYMultipleSeriesRenderer;
import org.achartengine.renderer.XYSeriesRenderer;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class ChartWeatherFragment extends Fragment {

    private LinearLayout chartLyt;
    private View v;
    private Animation fadeAnim;

    // London, UK
    private static final String CITY_ID = "2643743";

    private WeatherClient client;
    private List<DayForecast> dayForecast;
    private List<HourForecast> nextHourForecast;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        fadeAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.fade_anim);
        getData();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chart, container, false);
        chartLyt = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.chart);
        return v;
    }

    private void getData() {

        Log.d("ChartWeatherFragment", "getData method");

        final WeatherClient.ClientBuilder builder = new WeatherClient.ClientBuilder();

        WeatherConfig config = new WeatherConfig();
        config.lang = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
        config.maxResult = 5;
        config.numDays = 5;
        config.unitSystem = WeatherConfig.UNIT_SYSTEM.M;

        // Forecast IO API key
        // config.ApiKey = "6396685aea23558da6383a01d9725666";

        // Open Weather map API key
        config.ApiKey = "#####################################";

        try {
            client = builder.attach(getActivity())
                    .provider(new OpenweathermapProviderType())
                    .httpClient(com.survivingwithandroid.weather.lib.client.okhttp.
                            WeatherDefaultClient.class)
                    .config(config)
                    .build();
        } catch (WeatherProviderInstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        client.getHourForecastWeather(new WeatherRequest(CITY_ID), new WeatherClient.HourForecastWeatherEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onWeatherRetrieved(WeatherHourForecast weatherHourForecast) {
                nextHourForecast = weatherHourForecast.getHourForecast();
                chartLyt.addView(createTempGraph(), 0);
            }

            @Override
            public void onWeatherError(WeatherLibException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onConnectionError(Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }

    private View createTempGraph() {
        // We start creating the XYSeries to plot the temperature
        XYSeries series = new XYSeries("London Temperature hourly");

        // We start filling the series
        int hour = 0;
        for (HourForecast hf : nextHourForecast) {
            series.add(hour++, hf.weather.temperature.getTemp());
        }

        // Now we create the renderer
        XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        renderer.setLineWidth(2);
        renderer.setColor(Color.RED);
        // Include low and max value
        renderer.setDisplayBoundingPoints(true);
        // we add point markers
        renderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
        renderer.setPointStrokeWidth(3);


        // Now we add our series
        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataSet = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        dataSet.addSeries(series);

        // Finaly we create the multiple series renderer to control the graph
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);

        // We want to avoid black border
        mRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.argb(0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00));
        // Disable Pan on two axis
        mRenderer.setPanEnabled(false, false);
        mRenderer.setYAxisMax(35);
        mRenderer.setYAxisMin(0);
        mRenderer.setShowGrid(true); // we show the grid
        GraphicalView chartView = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(getActivity(), dataSet, mRenderer);

        // Enable chart click
        mRenderer.setClickEnabled(true);
        return chartView;
    }
}
```

**Stack trace:**

```
06-30 20:24:44.012    1903-1903/nl.inversion.weatherapp D/ChartWeatherFragment﹕ getData method
06-30 20:24:44.012    1903-1903/nl.inversion.weatherapp D/SwA﹕ Client [com.survivingwithandroid.weather.lib.client.okhttp.WeatherDefaultClient@b40a4ac8]
06-30 20:24:44.052    1903-1903/nl.inversion.weatherapp D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 220K, 10% free 3400K/3740K, paused 3ms, total 4ms
06-30 20:24:44.092    1903-1920/nl.inversion.weatherapp W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/nio/file/Path;)
06-30 20:24:44.092    1903-1920/nl.inversion.weatherapp W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature ([Ljava/nio/file/OpenOption;)
06-30 20:24:44.092    1903-1920/nl.inversion.weatherapp I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream, referenced from method okio.Okio.sink
06-30 20:24:44.092    1903-1920/nl.inversion.weatherapp W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static method 8451: Ljava/nio/file/Files;.newOutputStream (Ljava/nio/file/Path;[Ljava/nio/file/OpenOption;)Ljava/io/OutputStream;
06-30 20:24:44.092    1903-1920/nl.inversion.weatherapp D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x000a
06-30 20:24:44.092    1903-1920/nl.inversion.weatherapp W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/nio/file/Path;)
06-30 20:24:44.092    1903-1920/nl.inversion.weatherapp W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature ([Ljava/nio/file/OpenOption;)
06-30 20:24:44.092    1903-1920/nl.inversion.weatherapp I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream, referenced from method okio.Okio.source
06-30 20:24:44.092    1903-1920/nl.inversion.weatherapp W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static method 8450: Ljava/nio/file/Files;.newInputStream (Ljava/nio/file/Path;[Ljava/nio/file/OpenOption;)Ljava/io/InputStream;
06-30 20:24:44.092    1903-1920/nl.inversion.weatherapp D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x000a
06-30 20:24:44.302    1903-1920/nl.inversion.weatherapp D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 386K, 13% free 3525K/4032K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
06-30 20:24:44.302    1903-1920/nl.inversion.weatherapp W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3d2db20)
06-30 20:24:44.302    1903-1920/nl.inversion.weatherapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
    Process: nl.inversion.weatherapp, PID: 1903
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
            at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
            at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
            at org.achartengine.GraphicalView.<init>(GraphicalView.java:93)
            at org.achartengine.ChartFactory.getLineChartView(ChartFactory.java:71)
            at nl.inversion.weatherapp.ChartWeatherFragment.createTempGraph(ChartWeatherFragment.java:152)
            at nl.inversion.weatherapp.ChartWeatherFragment.access$100(ChartWeatherFragment.java:40)
            at nl.inversion.weatherapp.ChartWeatherFragment$1.onWeatherRetrieved(ChartWeatherFragment.java:101)
            at com.survivingwithandroid.weather.lib.client.okhttp.WeatherDefaultClient$6.onResponse(WeatherDefaultClient.java:381)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$AsyncCall.execute(Call.java:150)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:33)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

**Update, problem solved**

Thanks to

Since I was unable to use Activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()) I'm now using a handler which seems to work. Thanx!

Code snippit:

```
 client.getHourForecastWeather(new WeatherRequest(cityId),
            new WeatherClient.HourForecastWeatherEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onWeatherRetrieved(WeatherHourForecast weatherHourForecast) {
                    nextHourForecast = weatherHourForecast.getHourForecast();

                    /* Update UI
                    * Since callback is invoked on a background worker thread, create a handler
                    * to update the layout in the main UI thread
                    */
                    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            chartLyt.addView(createTempGraph(), 0);
                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void onWeatherError(WeatherLibException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                @Override
                public void onConnectionError(Throwable t) {
                    t.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
```

Comment: I'm investigating your problem. I added in the code:Handler handler = new Handler(ctx.getMainLooper());
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            listener.onWeatherRetrieved(currentWeather);
                        }
                    }); Can you open an issue at https://github.com/survivingwithandroid/WeatherLib

Comment: Hello Francesco, it's the same guy who has been bugging you on Google Plus about the Eclipse usage who ended up using Android Studio. Sorry to bother you again. Will open an issue though. Although its working witn the handler as specified below.

Comment: No prob, there should be a bug in that method you are using because it was intended on running on the main thread so you wouldn't have the problem you faced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the `onWeatherRetrieved()` callback is invoked on a background worker thread. You can only touch UI widgets on the main UI thread and hence the exception.

Use e.g. `Activity` `runOnUiThread()` to post a `Runnable` to be run on the main UI thread.